# Which one of these models is better?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was hoping to get a smart opinion on which one of these models would work better for my project. I need to store events, lists, text documents, and files, each one having a separate discussion thread. They also share many fields in common, like author, creation date, last update date, title, description, etc.

Model A:

Have a generic "items" table, with a "type" column that distinguishes each file type (docs, lists, events, files). Then, a comments or discussion table linking to this items table.

Possible Issues:

- Where would I store item-specific data, like the date itself if its a date? or the file's path if its a file.

Model B:

Having separate tables for lists, events, files and docs.

Possible Issues:

- Would have to specify both ID and type in the discussion/comments table

(You are also welcome to come up with a third model!)

Comment: C) Store all information that is generic to all item types in the `items` table. In table `lists` `events` etc. store rows that reference a row in the `items` table and contain all data that is a specific property of that item type.

Comment: That was fast! Thanks Patashu, will give it a try :)

Comment: @Patashu you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(adding as answer)

C) Store all information that is generic to all item types in the `items` table. In table `lists` `events` etc. store rows that reference a row in the items table and contain all data that is a specific property of that item type.